# Use react router in chrome extention

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-router

I try to use react router in a chrome extention.
When I use it on a normal webpage (localhost:3000) it works fine but when I build it and try it as a chrome extention it doesn't work.

Yeah I looked for solutions and found them but no one of then working for me.

This is my code:

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./App.css";

import Routers from "./Routers.js";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Routers />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Routers.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";

import Login from "./Login.js";
import Main from "./Main.js";



class Routers extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/main" component={Main} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Routers;
```

**Login.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./Login.css";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      room: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="joinOuterContainer">
          <input onChange={event => this.setState({ name: event.target.value })} />
          <input onChange={event => this.setState({ room: event.target.value })} />
          <Link to={`/main?name=${this.state.name}&room=${this.state.room}`}>
            <button type="submit">
              Sing In
            </button>
          </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: An extension html page is just a file, not a web page served by a server, so I guess the default router doesn't work. See if it has an alternative mode e.g. using hash routes.

Comment: See the [previously answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-router+google-chrome-extension) for possible solutions.

Comment: Hash routes work for me thank you so much.